# Windows popup: TeleDir.exe has stopped working (Code::Blocks)

Tags: c++, codeblocks

thanks in advance for taking a look at this.

I'm getting a Windows error message when I try to run this program I wrote in C in Code::Blocks. The funny thing is it compiles fine, and if I lower the upper bound of what I'm testing the program runs fine as well.

Details:

When I try to run the program, first I get a Windows popup that says "X.exe has stopped working. Windows is checking for a solution to the problem". Shortly this changes to "X.exe has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available. (Close program)" I click the close program button, and then I see the command prompt that says "Process returned -1073741819 <0xC0000005> execution time 11.151 s Press any key to continue".

I have Windows 7-64 bit.

I'm using the GNU GCC compiler.

Here's the code:

```
COORD coord={0,0};
void gotoxy(int x,int y)
{
    coord.X=x;
    coord.Y=y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),coord);
}

char *getname()
{ return name; }
char *getphno()
{ return mobile; }
int compare(char nm1[20])
{ if(strcmp(nm1,name)==0)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0; }
void update(char *nm,char *teleno){
strcpy(name,nm);
strcpy(mobile,teleno); }

char name[30];
char mobile[11];

public:
//MENU FUNCTIONS
void user_menu();  //to display the user menu
void admin_menu(); //to display the admin menu
void programmer_menu();

//WELCOME FUNCTIONS
void welcome();    //to display the welcome screen
void user();       //to display the user login
void admin();      //to display the admin login
void login();
void login1();
void programmer();

//OUTER FUNCTIONS
void add();        //to insert new number in TD
void display();    //to display all numbers in TD
void search();     //to perform searching in TD
void edit();       //to edit the Number in TD

//INNER FUNCTIONS
void showdata();   //to show data in TD
void search1();    //to search by name in TD
void search2();    //to search by number in TD
void modify();     //to modify the record of TD
void dele();       //to delete the record of TD
void code();       //to display the source code of TD
void password();
```

Comment: I'm Able to build the project but cannot able to run it. I have used Graphics.h in this code

Comment: You are getting a *crash*. You should run a debug-build in a debugger to catch the crash in action and learn where in your program it happens. When there you can examine the values of involved variables to help you understand what might have went wrong. [Please read more about how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you still can't figure it out, then edit your question to include those details (location and variable values).

Comment: Oh and you should find where you enable more warnings. Warnings are things that are probably bad and should be fixed, even though they are legal. For example like using uninitialized variables. Compilers these days are very good at finding things that are technically valid but could lead to *undefined behavior* and possible crashes when running.

Comment: I fixed all other warnings but could not able to understand about this particular one:

Comment: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]|

Comment: There are 28 warnings of this in my code

Comment: What's the purpose of the `compare` function? You should use the content of the `compare` function where you need it.   Also, you should use `bool`, `true` and `false` rather than an `int` and `1` and `0`.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` for text rather than C-Style character arrays.

Comment: How does the posted code compile?  Usually, the `public` keyword needs to be in a `class` or `struct`.

Comment: Thomas I by mistake typed it twice it's in the class itself above the starting of this code

Comment: #0 0x766e7878 KERNELBASE!GetLastError() (C:\Windows\syswow64\KernelBase.dll:??)
#1 0x438230 pthread_getspecific () (??:??)
#2 ?? ?? () (??:??)

Comment: showed this error when tried to debug my code